# Jenkins ssh-node doesn't find Java

Tags: java, jenkins, ssh

I try to connect Jenkins to a windows-machine, but during the connection process Jenkins tells me that it couldn't find java even thought I installed the newest Java-Version.

```
    [10/19/18 14:00:30] [SSH] Checking java version of /usr/local/java/bin/java
Couldn't figure out the Java version of /usr/local/java/bin/java

java.io.IOException: Java not found on hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer@d671ca. Install a Java 8 version on the Agent.
```

Comment: Try to ssh directly and do `java --version`. If it works then see  if there is `/usr/loca/hava/bin/java`.

Comment: Are your Jenkins installed on a windows machine?

Comment: When I type java --version the following error occurs. "An error has occurred while processing the shared archive file.
Unable to unmap shared space.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to use shared archive."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java isn't installed for the user that Jenkins is using?
Perhaps java is not on the classpath?
Is JAVA_HOME set?

Those are the places that I would start by looking

Comment: *java not on the classpath* - that is kind of impossible.

Comment: I already set the JAVA_HOME classpath but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Type `which java` in the slave agent and paste the path in the environment variables of the node in Jenkins

```
NAME: JAVA_HOME
Value: /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should ref a directory, not a command. Example: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`.